# Storing floating point numbers in a file

Tags: c, floating-point

For a C application that I am implementing, I need to be able to read and write a set of configuration values to a file. These values are floating point numbers. In the future it is possible that another application (could be written in C++, Python, Perl, etc...) will use this same data, so these configuration values need to be stored in a well defined format that is compiler and machine independent.

Byte order conversion functions (`ntoh/hton`) can be used to handle the Endianness, however what is the best way to get around the different meanings of "float" value? Is there are common method for storing floats? Rounding and truncating is not a problem, just as long as it is defined.

Comment: The best way to store a float (or any value for that matter), platform independent, is in text form. Storing it in binary form will not work, and using endianess functions will not help as there is no endianess defined for the binary representations of floating point values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Whilst there may be no standard defined endianness for binary floating point representations, it's easy enough to enforce one yourself. All you need to do is to decree that floating point values are stored in, say, big endian format.

Comment: You can use a standard type like IEEE754 doubles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are probably two main options:

1. Store in text format. Here you would standardise on a particular format using a well-defined decimal separator and use scientific notation, i.e. `6.66e42`.
2. Store in binary format using the IEEE754 standard. Use either the 4 or 8 byte data type. And as you noted, you'd have to settle on an endianness convention.

A text format is probably more portable because there are machines that do not natively understand IEEE754. That said, such machines are rare in these times.

Comment: Decimal does not give you portability because proper conversion between decimal numerals and binary floating-point is not as well supported as it ought to be. Most language standards do not require correctly rounded conversions, and various implementations do not guarantee them. In contrast, hexadecimal is easy to convert, even if you have to write your own conversion routine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Depends on your definition of portability. Have a look at how floating point values are typically persisted to XML, JSON, YAML and so on. If you need to have a lossless transfer then I agree, decimal may not be the right answer. But many scenarios don't require lossless transfer. The question explicitly stated that lossless transfer is not a requirement.

Comment: The question states that rounding or truncation are okay if it is defined. Would you please show me a language standard that does not require correct rounding in decimal/floating-point conversion but does define the rounding or truncation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I suggest you make representations to the designers of XML, JSON, YAML etc. and persuade them to change their designs.

Comment: I acknowledge there are powerful hammers for forcing square pegs into round holes. Nevertheless, it is not a good idea and damages the pegs.

Comment: @Eric Sometimes it is a good idea to store floating point values as decimal text. Anytime you want a human to read or write the file, then decimal is more useful. I definitely accept that decimal text is not the solution to every problem. It would seem to me that if anyone is guilty of force square pegs into round holes it is you with your inflexible views. There are many different problems, and many different solutions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This question popped up because someone voted on it. Ten years on I think it's reasonable to say that all major languages now have runtime libraries that perform correct conversion between decimal and binary representations.

Answer (score 4):

The C formatted input/output functions have a format specifier for this, `%a`. It formats a floating-point number in a hexadecimal floating-point format, *[-]*0x*h*.*hhhh*p±*d*. That is, it has a “-” sign if needed, hexadecimal digits for the fraction part, including a radix point, a “p” (for “power”) to start the exponent and a signed exponent of two (in decimal).

As long as your C implementation uses binary floating-point (or any floating-point such that its `FLT_RADIX` is a power of two), conversion with the `%a` format should be exact.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The hexadecimal floating-point format is easy to convert to and from binary floating-point. When converting numbers that came from the same binary format (hence, there are no extra digits that need to be rounded), there are no rounding issues.

Comment: But it may not be trivial in languages other than C. For example, what would be the code to do it in Perl? Is there a built in function to do it? I suspect that for many languages you'd need to roll your own. Which is why people may opt for the convenience of decimal at the expense of some round-trip precision loss.

Comment: For Perl, there is [`CPAN Data::Float`](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Data-Float-0.012/lib/Data/Float.pm).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *most* other common languages either use directly or provide some means of accessing the C standard library; in practice, it’s pretty easy for them to handle this format.

Answer (score 0):

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), or ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011, is the standard for floating point used by most languages.

For C, it's officially taken by standard in C11. (C11 Annex F *IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic*)

Comment: Annex F is optional; an implementation only need adhere to it if it defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

Answer (score 0):

For small amounts of data, such as configuration values, go with text not binary.  If you want, go for structured text of some form, such as JSON, XML.  Do decide on how many digits to write to represent a floating-point number according to your requirements.

As the range of required portability (across languages, operating systems, time, space, etc) increases so the force of the argument in favour of text becomes stronger.